# how to convert from struct tm to long int in C?

Tags: c, linux

this is a simple question ... is there a way to convert a `struct tm ct;` to a long integer ? here's how my code look like:

```
struct tm ct;
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_sec);
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_min);    
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_hour);
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_mday);
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_mon);
    scanf("%d", &ct.tm_year);
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with `long int`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `mktime()` function to convert a `struct tm` into a `time_t`, which is an integer value.

Comment: +1 and I don't think it's standard, but many OSes also have a `mkgmtime` which is the UTC equivalent.

Comment: As for UTC on Linux it's `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

you want to get a time_t, which represents the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00

use mktime():

time_t mktime ( struct tm * timeptr );

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/